# How can we use pjax without gridview in yii2?

Tags: gridview, yii2, pjax

I have a page with list of data in div I want to implement ajax pagination, can I do with pjax, I do not want to use gridview, because I will not get actual design in gridview what I required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside `Pjax` scope can be updated without reloading the whole page. For instance, instead of using `GridView` (with tables), you can easily implement what you want with `ListView`, so that it will look something like:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_item',
    'layout' => "{items}"
]); ?>
<?= LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $dataProvider->pagination,
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

ListView is similar to GridView with one main difference: you can assign a view for your items, so that you can display your $dataProvider items not only in a standard table, but any structure/design you like.

You can get more information about ListView in the official documentation: [Class yii\widgets\ListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html)

P.S. In the example above pagination is separated from the `ListView`. It shows that pagination element can be implemented anywhere (before and after `ListView`/`GridView`) as well  as well.